# WPF Datatrigger to set a StaticResource converter

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I have one DataTemplate and it contains a TextEdit (DevExpress component). I load three kind of types into the TextEdit: strings, integers and DateTimes. 
When the TextEdit displays a Datetime I want to use a converter. Otherwise, the TextEdit displays the original value (without converter). Maybe I can use a DataTrigger and when the type of my data is DateTime, use a Setter to set the DatetimeConverter. But how can I achieve that?I think, it is easy but I don't know how I can set the Converter only for DateTimes.

**UPDATE**

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
        <dxe:TextEdit Name="TxtNewValue" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      Text="{Binding TargetValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      Mask="{Binding TargetFieldDescription.fdValidateExp}" 
                      Loaded="FocusTextEditOnLoad"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Date}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="DateTime" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.DatTime}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="DateTime" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Time}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="RegEx" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TargetFieldType}" Value="{x:Static eva:FieldDataType.Num}">
                <Setter TargetName="TxtNewValue" Property="MaskType" Value="RegEx" />
            </DataTrigger>                
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>

    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understood your question properly but this `converter` should work:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dt))
        {
            return "it's a date";
        }
        else
        {
            return "not a date";
        }
    }
```

and i use it like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt1"/>
<TextBox x:Name="txt2" Text="{Binding ElementName=txt1, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"/>
```

so if the `Text property` of `txt1` can be parsed to a `DateTime` `Txt2` will behave accordingly.
Hope that you'll find it useful.

Comment: Thanks Yoav, yes it works. I mean, I have a ContentControl, depending on the type I want to use a TextBox with Converter or without Converter.

Comment: But I have only and only one DataTemplate...It's better and easier to define two DataTemplate: one with Converter and the other one without converter, isn't it?

Comment: You should upload an example with some code that will show what you are trying to achieve (how you load the data to the control, how your `xaml` looks like...)